# Point web app hosted on azure to a database on azure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, axios

I just recently split my back-end and front-end apart. I used to have them all in one file and run them concurrently. However, now I have split them apart for a little easier maintainability.

The problem I have having is actually configuring my front-end to point to the server itself for all requests.

I am using **React** for my front-end framework using **Axios** alongside Redux for API requests. Using **Express** for my back-end.

**Client package.json**

```
 {
      "name": "client",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "deploy": "npm run build",
        "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
        "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
        "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
        "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/material-dashboard-pro-react.css",
        "minify-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/material-dashboard-pro-react.min.css --output-style compressed",
        "map-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/material-dashboard-pro-react.css --source-map true"
      },
      ...
    }
```

**Server package.json**

```
{
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js --production"
  },
...
}
```

**Edit**
I went into one of my axios requests and added my database URL along with the api request like so..

```
post("https://jediacademy.azurewebsites.net/api/user/login", userData)
```

just to test it and I get this:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jediacademy.azurewebsites.net/api/user/login' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control 
check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So this is going to be my next issue i'm assuming. Hoping someone can enlighten me on connecting this along with pointing the app to the server dynamically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867323/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-a/49867665#49867665

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is common issue and called CORS.

Cross-origin resource sharing is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served.

so you should enable CORS in your back-end application. If u are using nodejs express you can simple enable that likewise.

`npm i cors --save`

```
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```